# Accept-Encoding: gzip: content is gzip-compressed twice

Tags: iis-7.5, gzip, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using IIS to serve a static file. I've configured IIS (using the GUI) to enable both static and dynamic compression.

I'm using `HttpClient` to download it, as follows:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
var stream = new FileStream("foo", FileMode.Create);
response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream)
                .ContinueWith(t => stream.Close())
                .Wait();
```

I'm inspecting the traffic using Fiddler, and I can see that the first one or two responses are not compressed. I assume that IIS is compressing the file in the background and caching it somewhere. The file written to disk is about 14MB (expected).

Later requests are compressed. I can see a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header in the response, and the file that is downloaded is about 360KB. It's a `gzip` file, as identified by Cygwin's `file` command.

However, when I use `gzip -d` to decompress it, I end up with a 660KB file which is, itself a gzip-compressed file, also identified by `file`.

If I decompress *that* file, I get back the 14MB file that I was expecting.

So: why is my file being compressed twice?

Comment: Programatically? i.e. not via IIS

Comment: It's a static XML file; other than IIS, nothing touches it.